# Facebook and JavaScript - getting user's name

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm kind of going crazy already - I'm trying to do a very simple facebook app that would just write my name. I had problems with php (my server doesn't support php5 and curl) so now I'm trying it in JavaScript. You can see the code I used here - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ under the sentence "The following HTML/JavasScript example demonstrates the client-side flow in one self-contained example:".

I have a problem - it does write my name, but:
1. only in one of my browsers - I have chrome and opera open, javascript allowed in both, in both logged on facebook, but my name displays only in chrome

1. when I add under userName.innerText = user.name; alert(user.name);, I get in both browsers alert message "undefined"

You can see it here: http://apps.facebook.com/krajecr/funguj.html

Do you know what's wrong? Thanks in advance...

---

Ok, I solved the alert thing - just made a new variable, which stored user.name and used that in the alert. Still no idea why it didn't work though and I still don't know what to do with opera

Answer (score 0):

Your page doesn't seem to work for me in FF. It may be to do with the order of your code - your callback could be being called before you have defined the displayName method? Try defining the displayName function first, before anything else.

You could try loading the javascript api asynchronously (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/). After you do FB.init(), check the user is logged in and authed, then you can get the name?